# why doesn't rocksdb cache key-value pair directly instead of block?

Tags: rocksdb

Rocksdb has LRU for caching blocks. But why doesn't it cache key-value pair directly to speed up single key read?
For getting a key, with block cache, one needs to locate the block (O(1)) and then maybe do a binary search inside a block to find the key.
But if cache keys directly, can get key in O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to handle block invalidation than key invalidation. When a block expire there might be many collocated keys that are touched, so you need to remove and add those new keys in the cache.

Whereas with the block approach, it is a single entry to replace.

Also, mind the fact that rocksdb is ordered, and a lot of operation will insert/delete/update keys that will be collocated.